# production.log has a big size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I'm running a Rails 3.0 application.
My problem is that the production.log is growing very fast.

Because I'm using caching, I get a lot of "Exist fragment?" entries in the log file.

I modified in config/environments/production.rb the following line:

**config.log_level = :fatal**, but this seems to have no effect.

In production mode, the site runs under Apache (with PhusionPassenger).

The log information seems to be the same as in development mode.

Does anybody has any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete this log file once it is too big. Make a backup if the data is important to you.

As per the below question...

[Ruby on rails log file size too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784057/ruby-on-rails-log-file-size-too-large)

Alternatively you can rotate the log file using `logrotate`, see the below answer...

[Ruby on Rails production log rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883891/ruby-on-rails-production-log-rotation/4883967#4883967)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The file is extremely big (growing with 500MB every day). I will use logrotate. However, modifying **config.log_level** in production.rb **should** have an impact. There is no difference between :fatal and :info.