# How to rotate log file on time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Now In the production.rb in environments I write code

```
config.logger = Logger.new("#{Rails.root.to_s}/log/production.log", 'daily')
```

So that do log file will rotate every day at midnight.

How do I write code for rotate log with `define time`?

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4883967/1241447 - using system logrotate.d

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#method-c-new - using built-in functionality