# Large log file in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, logging

I have a Rails 3 app in production and the production log is massive.  Can I safely delete this and allow Rails to generate another one?  Will I have to restart the Rails app or redeploy?  Will I have to touch production.log?

This thing is 300mb in size and I want to kill it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/home/deploy/appname/current/log/*.log {
  daily
  missingok
  rotate 7
  compress
  delaycompress
  notifempty
  copytruncate
}
```

Used logrotate with the above config and it's working nicely.

Answer (score 1):

add the whenever gem to your gem file

```
gem "whenever", "~> 0.7.2", require: false
```

and create a whenever task to do this

example run `wheneverize` commanad on your rails app
it will create a schedule.rb file for you in your config directory,
and you can add a task to it like

```
every 1.day, :at => '4:30 am' do
  rake "log:clear"
end
```

if you are using capistrano to deploy, add this to your deploy.rb

```
set :whenever_command, "bundle exec whenever"
```

this will authomatically set up whenever for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the logs whenever you want without fear for the application. 
Ideally, you should rotate those logs in order to prevent them becoming so big. You can do this using logrotate. For ubuntu, it would be something like this (as taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883891/ruby-on-rails-production-log-rotation)):

```
    /path/to/rails.example.com/tmp/log/*.log {
        weekly
        missingok
        rotate 52
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        create 640 root adm
        copytruncate
    }
```

[Here](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) is the logrotate man page for more information, though the instructions are somewhat self-explanatory.