# Is there a way to stop rails logging everything?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, privacy

I don't want it to log incoming IPs, I don't want it to log any internal happenings.
I just want Rails to process the requests as they come in and that's that.

Is this possible to do?

How can I prevent having a growing development.log or production.log?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why? Logs are extremely useful for debugging, especially when your application is in production.

Comment: If you're worried about the log size growing too large, you could always rotate your logs instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883891/ruby-on-rails-production-log-rotation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just replace the Rails logging facilities with loggers that log to /dev/null:

```
class NullLoggerRailtie < Rails::Railtie
  initializer 'null_logger', :before => 'initialize_logger' do |app|
    Rails.logger = ActiveRecord::Base.logger = ActionController::Base.logger = ::Logger.new("/dev/null")
  end
end
```

This will reroute all of the Rails logging to the null device, rather than letting it go to a file anywhere. The logging will still happen, but it'll just be immediately trashed.

Comment: Sweet. Does this also trash data like incoming IPs and such? I imagine it does.

Comment: It redirects all the output on those loggers to the null device - everything logged to them will end up being logged to nowhere, including IPs and errors and the like. :)

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted

Comment: It's worth noting that your webserver may still log IPs and whatnot in its own logs, so if you're going for full anonymization you'll want to take care of them, too.

Comment: I don't know if it'll be a problem since I'm writing this as an experimental app to be hosted on Tor.

Answer (score 3):

Set the log Level.

The available log levels are: `:debug, :info, :warn, :error` and `:fatal`

If you want to know the current log level you can call the Rails.logger.level method.

To change the log level use `config.log_level = :fatal` in your environment initializer, or
`Rails.logger.level = 0` inline at any time

Another option might be to symbolicly link the log file to /dev/null

Comment: Apologies, I misspoke (I have the hardest time coming up with titles for questions). What I really want to do is have rails save no records about ANY of the activity it has done. That includes logs (I will look into that, thanks) but also anything else. Does it store any other log info somewhere about who came to the site and what they did?

Comment: By the way, that doesn't seem to work for some reason. I added the config.log_level = :fatal to both production and development and I still get a whole bunch-o-logs which I'm sure are stored somewhere

Comment: Somewhere? Do you mean in `/log` at the application root.

Answer (score 2):

Simplifying [Chris Heald answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16072726/462015), you can set the logger to `/dev/null` by environment:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.logger = Logger.new("/dev/null")
end
```

Just place the code in the right file(s):

- Development: `config/environments/development.rb`
- Test: `config/environments/test.rb`
- Production: `config/environments/production.rb`
- All environments: `congig/applications.rb`