# gitlab - can i delete production.log and sidekiq.log

Tags: gitlab

I have a local gitlab installation, where in these 2 files production.log and sidekiq.log are taking too much space.
Just wondering is it safe to delete them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it is best to:

- stop the services first
- delete them in `gitlab/log`
- restart

You can also activate the **[logrotate](http://rubygems.org/gems/logrotate)** settings added [between 6.1 and 6.2](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/617cc8fb983f09ebcfb19493f78039d7829e167f/doc/update/6.1-to-6.2.md), to help manage the compression and rotation of those logs.

```
# Add support for lograte for better log file handling
sudo apt-get install logrotate
```

The latest 6.2 GitLab includes a:

[`lib/support/logrotate/gitlab`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/e9142c6f2cfcdf9a13bce375579085bd5ce00947/lib/support/logrotate/gitlab):

```
# GitLab logrotate settings
# based on: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4883967

/home/git/gitlab/log/*.log {
    weekly
    missingok
    rotate 52
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    copytruncate
}

/home/git/gitlab-shell/gitlab-shell.log {
    weekly
    missingok
    rotate 52
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    copytruncate
}
```

Comment: thanks @VonC I was able to delete, but seems like I won't be able to manage with this much space, can you also tell me how could i move the gitlab installation to another disk, I was able to lay my hands on another disk and added it to my ubuntu machine.

Comment: @BrijRajSingh Simply redo the installation and move your "`repositories`" folder from one machine to the other (or make a symlink from your new gitlab folder "`repositories`" to your current "`repositories`".

Comment: @BrijRajSingh note that also you can configure logrotate to compress and rotate your logs in any path you want, effectively moving the older logs elsewhere.

Comment: actually i just want to move the entire gitlab installation to another directory, just like that, I am not sure how a symlink would help me

Comment: @BrijRajSingh I wouldn't recommend a move. A symlink is only for the git repos stored in the `repositories` folder.