# Autorotation unicorn log file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn

I have unicorn config file in rails application:

config/unicorn.rb

```
app_name = "my_app"
root = "/home/user/my_sites/#{app_name}/current"

working_directory root
pid "#{root}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.err.log"
stdout_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.out.log"

listen "/tmp/unicorn.#{app_name}.sock"
worker_processes 2
timeout 30

before_exec do |_|
  ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"] = File.join(root, 'Gemfile')
end
```

How can auto rotate these log files?

For rails app and rails log I do:
Rails.logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join("log",Rails.env + ".log"), 3, 20*1024*1024)

What is the best solution for unicorn?

Answer (score 2):

Under `/etc/logrotate.d`  create a file name called `unicorn` (or the name of your app) and add below lines

```
/var/log/unicorn/*log {
    daily
    rotate 10
    missingok
    notifempty
    compress
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /bin/kill -USR1 $(cat /var/log/unicorn/unicorn.pid 2>/dev/null) 2>/dev/null || :
    endscript
}
```

According to [Unicorn's documentation](https://yhbt.net/unicorn/SIGNALS.html):

> USR1 - reopen all logs owned by the master and all workers See Unicorn::Util.reopen_logs for what is considered a log.

So `/bin/kill -USR1` will send this signal to the `unicorn`'s process using its `pid` from `/var/log/unicorn/unicorn.pid` (you may need to update according to yours).

`postrotate` is executed at end of `logrotate`'s rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Use [logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html)

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4883967/159721 for details