# gem for Rails log rotation and upload old logs to s3 bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, amazon-s3, fog

Is there a gem that would handle log rotation for Rails 4 **and** upload old logs to S3 ?

I'm googling for this for few hours and it sounds like something done by someone before (in gem form).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use one of these solutions [Ruby on Rails production log rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883891/ruby-on-rails-production-log-rotation)  and then just have `rake` task task that would move old logs to S3 bucket

`rake` task will be triggered by `crone` every night