# how to automatically zip logger files in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, zip

I have some logger files in my ruby on rails project and I want to zip them weekly or monthly.

```
log = Logger.new(log_address, 'daily')
```

how can i do that?
In addition, my log files are not Ruby on Rails production log and i'm working on ubuntu.

Comment: Look at this https://gorails.com/guides/rotating-rails-production-logs-with-logrotate

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails production log rotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883891/ruby-on-rails-production-log-rotation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use log rotation. Here is a great post how to do it:

https://gorails.com/guides/rotating-rails-production-logs-with-logrotate

Answer (score 1):

Use [logrotate](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/understanding-logrotate-utility) to rotate your logs on a daily or weekly basis no doubt in that but if possible try setting up an ELK(Elastic search, Logstash, Kibana) stack so make great use of logs like analysis, error rate, peak request time etc all these are available in Kibana. Logstash listens to your log file, or directory it flexible enough to configure as a lot of pugins are available, and then indexes them on elastic search server, and Kibana dispays the indexed data