# Log rotation for custom log files in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, log-rotation

I would like to know how we can rotate custom log files in ruby on rails. I have searched and found ways to rotate the environment log files(development.log, production.log). But my requirement is to rotate every log files in the application.

This can be done with the logrotate tool. But, I would like to handle log rotation from the application itself.

How is this possible with the rails logger class?

Is there a generic way we can do this(may be in the application.rb) instead of specifying the shift age and file size wherever creating each of these application logs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is clearly an offtopic on SO. Also, the question has literally **nothing** to do with [tag:ruby], so I removed the tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails production log rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883891/ruby-on-rails-production-log-rotation)